# Relative XPath not working in IE

Tags: selenium, xpath, ui-automation

When I identified working XPath in Chrome Version 54.0.2840.71 m (64-bit) and Firefox 49.0.1 , is not working in IE 11.545.10586.0 . ( All are latest version )

```
XPath= //input[@id="UserId"]
```

I want to use XPath only as it gives more flexibility of write Expression .

Is this problem of XPath engine of IE ?

Comment: IE doesn't support XPATH over the HTML DOM, only CSS selectors. If you really want XPATH you can add a custom library like this http://coderepos.org/share/wiki/JavaScript-XPath and use script commands (I never tried, just an idea)

Comment: You can get most of the selectors with css, there are few exceptions like contains text or navigating to parent/ancestor, and is very easy, please take a look at http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp

Comment: Thank you @SimonMourier for answer , as per your comment if I go I need to import JavaScript in IE on browser on all PC , if my script going for RemoteDesktop browser I need to add on IE of desktop I think this will not be feasible ...... for CSS there are some restriction like case insensitive (works for chrome , firefox but not on IE for ex: css = div[id='SpendByVendorPiechart' i]) thatwhy I am not using .

Comment: @lauda - Thanks for answer ,  for CSS there are some restriction like case insensitive (works for chrome , firefox but not on IE for ex: css = div[id='SpendByVendorPiechart' i]) thatwhy I am not using .

Comment: Depends, on attributes you have alternatives, like: css = div[id=SpendByVendorPiechart], div[id=spendbyvendorpiechart]   This can be used as a single selector (copy with comma included).You can also select partial value from id like div[id*=endor][id*=iechart]

Comment: Your element is probably not yet present at the time you are trying to locate it. Try with an explicit waiter. Note that @Simon Mourier is wrong in this context, Selenium/IE supports XPath, but it is slower compared to an CSS selector.

Comment: @lauda , above answer applied it worked in IE but  not working as expected , it finding more than 1 element in IE , but in chrome , firefox it finding 1 . Strange ....

Comment: @FlorentB. , element is present ,   I checked manually ( not with automated script ) in IE to find element in "Inspect Element " section with XPath , and it not identifying the element , but in Chrome and FF , it identifying (checked manually ) .

Comment: @Rakesh, it's hard to say why without the html. Try to locate the body and then each descendant leading to your element to see if the locator is the issue. Also try with an explicit waiter.

Comment: @FlorentB. - Selenium does supports XPATH of course, but IE doesn't AFAIK. Are you sure? what version?

Comment: @Simon Mourier, the OP is about driving IE through Selenium with an XPath locator. Your comment says that he needs to add a library to support it, which is not true. Selenium can locate an element with an XPath with IE (8, 9, 10, 11). So saying that it's not natively supported by IE is irrelevant in this context since the driver automatically injects its own code (wgxpath) to provide the support.